# Nodejs: rabbitmq await consume

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

This is my code:

```
// send to queue
channel.sendToQueue("test", data);
```

After publish `test`, on another server we get a response from that server

So, I want to await for it and get with await:

```
await channel.consume("response", async (msg) => {
  ....
})
```

But await not work here

How can I await for consume?

My full code:

```
channel.sendToQueue("test", data);
await channel.consume("response", async (msg) => {
  ....
})
// continue code
```

Comment: You'll probably need to wrap the `consume` call in a promise if you want to await it

Comment: @DaneBrouwer can you help me more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a promise and wrap it around your consume function call.
It's a callback so we can just call `resolve` to make our outer promise actually resolve.

`channel.consume` doesn't return an awaitable response so we cannot `await` it.

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  channel.consume("response", (msg) => {
    resolve(msg);
  })
})
```